# Stable and unstable manifold for a 2D dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, chaos-theory

In ["*Differential Equations*" by Stephen Wiggins](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Ordinary_Differential_Equations_(Wiggins)/zz%3A_Back_Matter/02%3A_F%3A_A_Brief_Introduction_to_the_Characteristics_of_Chaos) (Example F.45) it is said that for the simple dynamical system
$$\dot x=\lambda x$$
$$\dot y=\mu y$$

where $(x, y) \in R^2$ and $\lambda, \mu > 0$, we have that the $x$ axis is the unstable manifold, whereas the $y$ axis is the stable one.
I could not figure how the second assertion could be true

Comment: there's a mistake there, one of the numbers should be negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, these uncoupled system has solution
$$x=ke^{\lambda t},$$
and
$$y=le^{\mu t}.$$
Since both $\lambda, \mu$ are positive then the system is unstable.

It is necessary that $\mu<0$ to get stability along the $y$-axis.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!